How can I find the exact csc.exe command that is run by IIS/ASP.NET?
How can I find the exact csc.exe command that is executed when I start up my ASP.NET application in IIS? When there is a compilation error, I see the full csc.exe command on the error page in my browser. But what about when the application compiles without error? Is there a log file somewhere?

Not really a log file but the complete result of compiling your dynamic assets is [somewhere in the asp.net temporary files folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms366723(v=vs.100). Since the compilation is two-step, first is compiling resources to C# and only then C# compiler is automatically invoked, I doubt the invocation does something extra you should be aware of (i.e. I doubt you need to know what exact command is invoked).

@Charlieface: the question is apparently about .NET Framework.

Right - .NET Framework, not .NET Core - sorry if that was not clear.

@WiktorZychla - I am troubleshooting compiler error "CS1647". My reading suggests lots of possible root causes for this error. In my case, it seems to be related to the number of assemblies, whether directly or indirectly. However, I am struggling to pinpoint precisely what is causing the error. I am running a bunch of experiments, some which cause this error and others that do not. I was hoping to compare the exact csc.exe command across all experiments. Note I don't expect to solve this "CS1647" error in this question - just explaining why I am interested in the exact csc.exe command.

There may be a better way, but you'd probably be able to see this with Sysinternal's Process Monitor (ProcMon) and/or Process Explorer. They're incredibly valuable tools to have for anyone that has to debug issues on Windows.

@mason your suggestion gave me the idea to check Task Manager and I was able to get it that way. There was one level of indirection (the command referenced some file which contained the full command) but I was able to get the information I was looking for. Thanks.

Here is how to find the full csc.exe command using Windows Task Manager.
Open Task Manager > Details tab. Right-click a column header and click "Select columns". Select the "Command line" column to make it appear in the grid.
Restart IIS and load your application.
While the application is loading, find csc.exe on the Details tab in Task Manager. Copy the row to a text editor. The command will look something like this:
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /noconfig /fullpaths @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\my-app\aaa\bbb\ccc.cmdline"

Find that *.cmdline file. It will contain the rest of the full command. The final command, as far as I can tell, will be something like this:
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" <content-from-*.cmdline-file>

NOTE: During my testing I observed two *.cmdline files which I guess means there were multiple commands executed. When I forced an error and reviewed the full csc.exe command on the error page, it matched the latter of the two *.cmdline files.
